# Passing double equal sign in value in POSTMAN using raw text body

Tags: api, http, post, arduino, postman

I'm using POSTMAN to send parameter to an API using raw text format. The data i sent has two equal sign in the end in one of the parameters. Lets say i have a variable a, b, and c. Variable a value is 1234567890==; so i write the full raw text as follow :

a=123456789==&b=1234&c=1234

but the postman didn't recognize the double equal sign at the end of variable a value, so it was like the POSTMAN does not recognized the double equal sign other than the separator between key and value. I tried using the x-form-www-urlencoded body it can send the double equal sign, but when i used raw text format it cannot. I'm required to use the raw text format to send the parameter to the API. How can i fix my problem.

Thank you

Comment: How is this related to 'Arduino' you tagged?

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot to tell that i'm using ESP32 and arduino HTTPClient

Comment: Then the problem is in your code that you didn't shown.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't attach my program earlier, but it has the same result when I'm using POSTMAN or using HTTPClient, so maybe i think that the problem is the API i'm using. Thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this using `postman-echo` and the data was sent properly. Check [this sample request I've created for you](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/vitor-s-sandbox/request/19391207-08fe7b4f-c0a1-4493-a652-a0abbcfd97bb).

As you can see I set the Body to the payload above, with `raw` `text` format:

[image]

Postman-echo replies exactly with the same payload, which means the server would have gotten the data as is{:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i still quite couldn't understand it either. I tried to use the encode version for the equal sign, which is %3d but still couldn't detect the equal sign. I guess the error comes from the API itself

Comment: I believe so, yes.